# Adding a splash screen to my project

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a project which consist of a `tabbarcontroller` and a `navigationcontroller`.

The first view or the first tab is a tableview controller. Now i need to add a splashscreen to my application, so when the app loads it will show a welcome screen and then land on the tableviewcontroller.

My workings so far;

This is added in my `viewDidLoad` method.

```
myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.jpg"]];
myImageView.frame = [[self view] frame];

[self.view addSubview:myImageView];    
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.myImageView];
```

The problem is that the splash screen or the `UIImageView` loads inside the tabbarController/NavigationController, and it does not take the full width and length of the screen. What should i do to fix this programatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In application bundle you need to copy the splash screen images with the name "Default.png" and "Default@2x.png" for Retina. The app will load this automatically, you don't need to do more work.

Here you have a link for this: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/defaultpng-the-secret-of-the-load-screen.html

Comment: You mean that i need not write a single line of code, but just add `Default.png`, and the splashscreen will appear ? :S

Comment: Thank you for the link. but i have also seen applications with animated splash screen images. I don't think one could add .gif images so from where did the animation come ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with my solution. A similar question about what you want is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169792/iphone-ipad-animated-splash-screen

Answer (score 4):

Add the images that you want to use to the resources of your project and name them `Default.png` and `Default@2x.png` (if you are providing it for a retina screen). Be sure no name them exactly. If you get the capitalisation wrong, it will work in the Simulator (which is not case-sensitive), but not on the device (which is case-sensitive).

Be aware that a "splash screen" is discouraged by the Apple Human Interface Guidelines:

[image]

Comment: My first screen requires to download data and populate the table. So until that hapence i am trying to load an imageView with an activity indicator on it. So is this Ok ? and is it in accordance to Apple Human interface guildlines ?

Comment: This won't work for that. The Default screen is only shown until the view is available. You are better off loading your initial view controller, and loading your resources asynchronously while displaying some default or cached data. You can still display an activity indicator.

Comment: Could you kindly share the URL for Apple Human Interface Guidelines where it says the above.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html under the section on Launch Images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the Launch Images a look in your target settings?

Comment: Yes, The image displays, but inside the tabBar. Example : the first tab becomes the splash screen image. Actually the whole view should be the splashScreen

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to add the splash screen in the app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. Then start an animation of fade out (or whatever animation you need). Finally removing the splash screen view when the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `UIImageView` to the root's view:

```objc
  UIView *rootView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController] view];
  [myImageView setFrame:rootView.bounds];
  [rootView addSubview:myImageView];
```

Comment: Ok then how can i remove it after awhile ?

Comment: Yeah, you can use a `NSTimer` or `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the uiimage view to add an array of images to play an animation, try the following 
code in

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    animationSplashImageView.animationImages = imageArray;
    animationSplashImageView.animationDuration = 5;
    animationSplashImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [animationSplashImageView startAnimating];
} 


IBOutlet UIImageView* animationSplashImageView;
```

was defined in the main view of your app.

also you could test your splash using tool Splashx Free, which is on Apple App Store: http://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/splashx-free/id500137095?mt=8